# Como poner 2 RecyclerView en 2 columnas?

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de hacer dos listas para hacer scroll independientemente, estoy usando dos recyclerview para mostrar las listas. Quiero algo como esto:

[image: dos reciclerviews]

Al ejecutar no se muestra nada en la pantalla (todo en blanco), este es el codigo de mi xml:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lista1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lista2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Esta es mi clase java con los adaptadores, por cuestiones de pruebas he repetido el codigo para mi segundo recyclerview:

```
public class Test extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_test,
            container, false);

    Query dbPredicciones =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("prediccion");

    Query dbPredicciones2 =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("prediccion");

    RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista1);
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    RecyclerView recycler2 = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista2);
    recycler2.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    PushNotifyActivity.mAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<History, PrediccionesHolder>(
                    History.class, R.layout.item_list, PrediccionesHolder.class, dbPredicciones) {

                @Override
                public void populateViewHolder(PrediccionesHolder predViewHolder, History pred, int position) {

                }
            };

    PushNotifyActivity.mAdapter2 =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<History, PrediccionesHolder>(
                    History.class, R.layout.item_list, PrediccionesHolder.class, dbPredicciones2) {

                @Override
                public void populateViewHolder(PrediccionesHolder predViewHolder, History pred, int position) {

                }
            };

    recycler.setAdapter(PushNotifyActivity.mAdapter);
    recycler2.setAdapter(PushNotifyActivity.mAdapter2);
    return view;
}

public static class PrediccionesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private View mView;

    public PrediccionesHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.mView = itemView;
    }

}
```

}

**Nota:** Haciendo mis pruebas he colocado `android:orientation="vertical"` en el linearlayout de mi xml y me muestra los dos recyclerview con los items, pero lo que busco es que esten en paralelo como el la primera imagen.

[image: reciclerview ambos en vertical]

Comment: Creaste el adaptador de la segunda lista? cada lista debe tener su adaptador. Puedes llenarlas con los mismo datos para pruebas, pero deben ser adaptadores diferentes para mejor comprensión de código.

Comment: Ojo si quiere dos columnas de los datos de una misma BD, recyclerview tienes una propiedad que lo puede poner en columnas, en cuadrícula, y en lista, ahora sí quiere más de una columna de diferente BD tienes que hacer una Adapter para cada una de ellas, espero que me haya comprendido suerte.

Comment: Gracias por responder, he editado mi pregunta con el codigo de los adaptadores, y he cambiado ´orientation="vertical´ en mi xml y si me carga las dos listas

Answer (score 2):

El contenedor, debe ser horizontal y el peso `android:layout_weight=1`definido es correcto para ambos elementos ya que tendran un ancho de 50% cada Recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"

    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lista1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lista2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Pero también debes eliminar el uso de `setHasFixedSize(true)`

```
 RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista1);
 recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
 recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
```

> [setHasFixedSize(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setHasFixedSize(boolean)) El RecyclerView puede realizar varias
>   optimizaciones si puede saber de antemano que el tamaño del
>   RecyclerView no se ve afectado por el contenido del adaptador.

de esta forma podrás obtener el resultado deseado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando desees utilizar varios RecyclerView en un mismo layout te sugiero no usar esta opción, revisa este ejemplo:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-RecyclerView-HorizontalVertical

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

El problema era por esta linea:

```
recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Quité la linea y funciono como esperaba, espero que le sirva a alguien mas.